# Why I get error message RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity

Once I want to make chat beetwen Manager and Admin I get error, but couple of minute ago it works fine.
Not sure why I get this kind of error since `Application.User.Role` exsisting in my `db` and it it not null

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SendDiscussion(int ticketId, string message)
        {
            var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var account = _db.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName.Equals(userName));

            var discussion = new Discussion
            {
                DateAndTime = DateTime.Now,
                Content = message,
                TicketId = ticketId,
                UserId = account.Id
            };
            _unitOfwork.Discussion.Add(discussion);
            _unitOfwork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = ticketId });
        }
```

And here is View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-primary direct-chat direct-chat-primary">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Discussion</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="direct-chat-messages">
                    @if (ViewBag.discussion != null)
                    {
                        @foreach (var discussion in ViewBag.discussion)
                        {
                            <div class="direct-chat-msg @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "" : "right")">

                                <div class="direct-chat-infos clearfix">
                                    <span class="direct-chat-name @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Manager" ? "float-right" : "float-left")">@discussion.ApplicationUser.Name</span>
                                    <span class="direct-chat-timestamp @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "float-left" : "float-right")">@discussion.DateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                    @discussion.Content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <form asp-controller="Ticket" asp-action="SendDiscussion" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        @if (Model.Ticket.Status.ToString() == "Otvoren" || Model.Ticket.Status.ToString() == "NaCekanju")
                        {
                            <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Message ..." class="form-control">
                            <span class="input-group-append">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                            </span>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ticketId" asp-for="Ticket.Id" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error message is throw at this line

```
<div class="direct-chat-msg @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "" : "right")">
```

Why I get this kind of error ? Since it was work fine couple of minutes ago and right now I get error.
I try to Remove-Migration folder and starting from begginer, creating  database and update database but doesn't work at all.
Anyone how know where error coming from ?

Comment: Can you show the Error Message you are getting may be you are getting error message on wrong login Role

Comment: Sure. `RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`
In this line 
` <div class="direct-chat-msg @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "" : "right")">` Details.cshtml

Comment: this `ViewBag.discussion` is null. Where do you set that `discussion` on `ViewBag`?

Comment: I found error. Since in my method I didnt pass `ApplicationUser` and this throw error, and I didn't `includeProperties` in `ViewBag.discussion`

Comment: It seems that you have already found the reason. In the `SendDiscussion` method, the `discussion` class just contains four properties, without the `ApplicationUser`, you could try to add the `Role` property in the `discussion` class.